# Call method once when Flask app started despite many Gunicorn workers

Tags: flask, gunicorn, flask-cache, flask-caching

I have a simple Flask app that starts with Gunicorn which has 4 workers.

I want to clear and warmup cache when server restarted. But when I do this inside `create_app()` method it is executing 4 times.

```py
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # ...  different configuration here

    t = threading.Thread(target=reset_cache, args=(app,))
    t.start()
    return app
```

```
[2022-10-28 09:33:33 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
[2022-10-28 09:33:33 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2022-10-28 09:33:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
[2022-10-28 09:33:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2022-10-28 09:33:36,908 INFO     webapp reset_cache:38      Clearing cache
2022-10-28 09:33:36,908 INFO     webapp reset_cache:38      Clearing cache
2022-10-28 09:33:36,908 INFO     webapp reset_cache:38      Clearing cache
2022-10-28 09:33:36,909 INFO     webapp reset_cache:38      Clearing cache
```

How to make it only one-time without using any queues, rq-workers or celery?
Signals, mutex, some special check of worker id (but it is always dynamic)?
Tried Haven't found any solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

I used Redis locks for that.

Here is an example using [flask-caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which I had in project, but you can replace set `client` from whatever place you have redis client:

```py
import time

from webapp.models import cache  # cache = flask_caching.Cache()


def reset_cache(app):
    with app.app_context():
        client = app.extensions["cache"][cache]._write_client  # redis client

        lock = client.lock("warmup-cache-key")
        locked = lock.acquire(blocking=False, blocking_timeout=1)
        if locked:
            app.logger.info("Clearing cache")
            cache.clear()

            app.logger.info("Warming up cache")
            # function call here with `cache.set(...)`
            app.logger.info("Completed warmup cache")

            # time.sleep(5)  # add some delay if procedure is really fast
            lock.release()
```

It can be easily extended with threads, loops or whatever you need to set value to cache.